# product of a compact and non compact submanifolds

Tags: general-topology, manifolds

Let $M$ be a compact submanifold of $\mathbb R^N$, is it true that 
$M\times \mathbb R$ is a **compact** submanifold of $\mathbb R^{N+1}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can’t be compact: for any $x\in M$, $\{x\}\times\Bbb R$ is a closed subset that isn’t compact.

Comment: Unless $M$ is empty, of course.

Comment: @Chris: Well, the part **after** the colon is still true! :-)

Comment: for each $x\in M$, $\{x\}\times \mathbb R$ is not compact because it is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R$ which is not compact. It remains to see why this implies that $M\times \mathbb R$ is not compact?

Comment: @palio: Every closed subset of a compact space is compact, so if $M\times\Bbb R$ were compact, $\{x\}\times\Bbb R$ would be compact.